# How can i access a variable from Firebase API file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, reactjs-flux

Well, i'm new to flux architecture and understand quite a lot of how it works now but I don't understand how i should be able to export and access doAuth function into Login.js from appAPI.js in order to display the message, i do understand and able to do it with local state, i once thought of creating a new action for the same, however, it's throwing me `dispatch.dispatch(...) cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch` probably because i believe i can make this work using the same action. Can someone please help what am i suppose to do ?

Thanks in advance !!.

appAPI.js

```
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
    var Firebase = require('firebase');
    module.exports = {
       signInUser: function(user) {
              const auth = firebase.auth();
              const doAuth = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.username,user.password)
                   .then(() => console.log('User logged in'))
                   .catch(e => console.log(e.message))
          }
    }
```

Login.js

```
var React = require('react');
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');

var Login = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
       return(
       ...
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                  <input type="text" ref={username => {this.username = username}}/>
                    <label className="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="password" ref={password => {this.password = password}}/>
                    <label className="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
              </form>
       ...
       )
    },


    onSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var user = {
        username: this.username.value,
        password: this.password.value
      }
      AppActions.signInUser(user);
    },

});

module.exports = Login;
```

AppStores.js

```
....

var _user = [];

var AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    getSignInUser: function() {
      return _user;
    },
    signInUser: function(user) {
        _user.push(user);
    }
   ...
});

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
    var action = payload.action;
    switch(action.actionType) {
        case AppConstants.SIGNIN_USER:
            AppStore.signInUser(action.user);
            AppAPI.signInUser(action.user);
            break;
    }

    return true;
});

module.exports = AppStore;
```

AppActions.js

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');

var AppActions = {
  signInUser: function(user) {
    AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
        actionType: AppConstants.SIGNIN_USER,
        user: user
    });
  }
}

module.exports = AppActions;
```

App.js

```
...

function getAppState() {
    return {
        users: AppStore.getSignInUser(),
    }
}

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return getAppState();
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
       AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        AppStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
           <div>
              <Login user={this.state.users}/>
           </div>
       )
    },
    _onChange: function() {
      this.setState(getAppState());
   }

});

module.exports = App;
```

Comment: Hello, can you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I was trying to create an action AppActions.receiveMsg(user) in appAPI.js inside signInUser (which seems to be wrong )and then passing it to AppActions.js then to AppStores.js ending up creating a new state and then trying to access this state as props in Login.js